# Set property based on whether data context reference equals another object

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding

The title is probably unclear, but seeing code should help. Suppose I have this viewmodel:

```
class Foo
{
    string Name { get; set; }
}    

class MyViewModel
{
    Foo MagicFoo { get; set; }
    IEnumerable<Foo> AllFoos { get; set; }
}
```

I'd like to use an instance of `MyViewModel` as the `DataContext` for this `ComboBox`:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding AllFoos}">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

But... I would like to make the text bold if the row's `Foo` reference-equals `MagicFoo`. I couldn't get a trigger or a valueconverter to work because in both cases, you can't use databinding on the right-hand side (the `Value` property in the case of a trigger, `ConverterParameter` in the case of a ValueConverter). Is there another way to do this?

Comment: either adapt your viewmodel to have a boolean flag, or use a MultiBinding with an `IMultiValueConverter` that checks for equality.

Comment: @HighCore `IMultiValueConverter` is what I was looking for. Want to make it an answer?